# Compile time error with Guava's Iterables.any()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, compiler-errors, guava

I'm getting an error for the following code:

```
Iterables.any(Lists.<String>newArrayList(), new Predicate<String>() {
  @Override
  public boolean apply(final String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
  }
});
```

The error:

> The method any(`Iterable<T>, Predicate<? super T>`) in the type
>   Iterables is not applicable for the arguments (`ArrayList<String>, new`
>   `Predicate<String>(){}`)

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I'm making a silly mistake.

Comment: What do your imports look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops - I was using the wrong import.

Correct:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
```

Incorrect:

```
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
```

Using the `repackaged` Guava leads to problems.

Comment: Would be nice if the compiler error message showed the full package names (only) in cases like this.